# How to display data in a table inside a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, xcode5

I have a ViewController in which I put another small UIView in the middle where I have placed a TableView but not how to display data from an array in this table, could help.

[image: UIView]

I try putting UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource and methods numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection, numberOfRowsInSection

It does not work

Comment: Have you connected the tableView's delegate/dataSource to the class/classes that implement those methods?

Comment: I'm sorry I do not know how do it

Comment: Adding it inside another view does not change the behavior of a tableView. Maybe you are getting confused with tableViewController which is another thing. You just need to create a property of tableView, set the delegate and datasource and implement the methods that are required.

Answer (score 0):

First set UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource.

Then use below methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return generateImageOptionsArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

Hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

The main method you are missing is:
cellForRowAtIndexPath
Which is used to display the cells and adjust thier info... And make sure you call the show view in an async dispatch in the main queue.

Comment: I have it but don't work, I do not know how connect de tableView to the delegate/dataSource